# Windows 10 unpinning updated apps: how to prevent?

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, pin

I create my pinned entries in startmenu, group them nicely, resize them etc so that it fits my needs but then when I update an app, windows just removes it from the menu and I have to repeat it all over again. How can I prevent that? And is this a windows problem or an app problem?

Comment: I am guessing.. but when the app gets updated, it is certainly a DIFFERENT exe than before, possibly even in a new path.  Windows has no way to know that this app is actually the old app in the other place.

Comment: All of the pins in the start menu and taskbar are shortcuts, so it is true that if the path or filename changed, the shortcut isn't going to work anymore. It usually doesn't disappear until you click on it once if that is the issue. That is unlikely to happen to all pinned apps at once. I was able to find a lot of reports of this problem by changing the wording of my search from 'pinned apps removed' to 'pinned apps disappear'. The results when using 'removed' are flooded on how to remove a pinned app. Just had 30 Windows Store updates to test, I pinned a bunch of apps, updated, nothing moved

Comment: So, this functionality should work for you. You may have an issue with your windows installation. The posts by Microsoft to run the system checks is probably not a bad idea. sfc /scannow and potentially also the dism.exe commands and options.

Answer (score 0):

The comments helped me at least find out why it happens but it doesn't solve the issue. The issue seems to stem from the actual products and how they are updated (Jetbrains tools via Jetbrains toolbox).

It seems the toolbox doesn't actually do an update but does a completey fresh install and the path to the exe actually changes as the path contains the full build number for the application.

I contacted the vendor about this issue but it certainly isn't a windows problem.